# How to disallow start of new game when game is over?

Tags: javascript

I can't figure how to have the game end when a player either loses or wins. What am I doing wrong? This is what I have so far.        Any suggestions would be helpful, thanks!

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Hangman</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"><!--
gallows = new Array("--------\n|      |\n|\n|\n|\n|\n=====",
"--------\n|      O\n|\n|\n|\n|\n=====",
"--------\n|      O\n|      |\n|\n|\n|\n=====",
"--------\n|      O\n|     \\|\n|\n|\n|\n=====",
"--------\n|      O\n|     \\|/\n|\n|\n|\n=====",
"--------\n|      O\n|     \\|/\n|      |\n|\n|\n=====",
"--------\n|      O\n|     \\|/\n|      |\n|     /\n|\n=====",
"--------\n|      O\n|     \\|/\n|      |\n|     / \\\n|\n=====")
guessChoices = new
Array("summertime")
    {
 guesses = 0
 max = gallows.length-1
 guessed = " "
 len = guessChoices.length - 1
 toGuess = guessChoices[Math.round(len*Math.random())].toUpperCase()
 displayHangman()
 displayToGuess()
 displayGuessed()
}
function stayAway() {
 document.game.elements[3].focus()
 alert("Don't mess with this form element!")
}
function displayHangman() {
 document.game.status.value=gallows[guesses]
}
function displayToGuess() {
 pattern=""
 for(i=0;i<toGuess.length;++i) {
  if(guessed.indexOf(toGuess.charAt(i)) != -1)
   pattern += (toGuess.charAt(i)+" ")
  else pattern += "_ "
 }
 document.game.toGuess.value=pattern
}
function displayGuessed() {
 document.game.guessed.value=guessed
}
function badGuess(s) {
 if(toGuess.indexOf(s) == -1) return true
 return false
}
function winner() {
 for(i=0;i<toGuess.length;++i) {
  if(guessed.indexOf(toGuess.charAt(i)) == -1) return false
 }
 return true
}
function guess(s){
 if(guessed.indexOf(s) == -1) guessed = s + guessed
 if(badGuess(s)) ++guesses
 displayHangman()
 displayToGuess()
 displayGuessed()
 if(guesses >= max){
 alert("You're dead.")
 }
 if(winner()) {
  alert("You won!")
 }
}
// --></SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Hangman</H1>
<FORM NAME="game">
<PRE>
<TEXTAREA NAME="status" ROWS="7" COLS="16"
 ONFOCUS="stayAway()"></TEXTAREA>
</PRE><P>
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="toGuess"
 ONFOCUS="stayAway()"> Enter this word in the promo code box!<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="guessed"
 ONFOCUS="stayAway()"> Letters you have guessed.<BR>
<P>Enter your next guess.</P>
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" A " ONCLICK="guess('A')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" B " ONCLICK="guess('B')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" C " ONCLICK="guess('C')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" D " ONCLICK="guess('D')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" E " ONCLICK="guess('E')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" F " ONCLICK="guess('F')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" G " ONCLICK="guess('G')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" H " ONCLICK="guess('H')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" I " ONCLICK="guess('I')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" J " ONCLICK="guess('J')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" K " ONCLICK="guess('K')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" L " ONCLICK="guess('L')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" M " ONCLICK="guess('M')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" N " ONCLICK="guess('N')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" O " ONCLICK="guess('O')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" P " ONCLICK="guess('P')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" Q " ONCLICK="guess('Q')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" R " ONCLICK="guess('R')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" S " ONCLICK="guess('S')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" T " ONCLICK="guess('T')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" U " ONCLICK="guess('U')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" V " ONCLICK="guess('V')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" W " ONCLICK="guess('W')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" X " ONCLICK="guess('X')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" Y " ONCLICK="guess('Y')">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" Z " ONCLICK="guess('Z')"><P>

</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I am just learning this so please be simple in your reply. Thanks!

Comment: The code works. I get the message "You won!" when I enter the correct characters. What is the problem? Note that you should move your script to the end of the HTML document, so that the start-up code can reference the form. Yet, this issue does not prevent you from playing until the end.

Comment: Hey, there...thanks for your help! Yes, you are correct, it does give the message. But when a person loses, it also gives the message but even after that, it lets you keep continuing to choose a letter until the puzzle is solved. Losing should end the game and not allow any more play. Try playing it purposely to lose and then after the game tells you that you have lost, try choosing another letter and see what I am referring to. The point is that the game should end if you lose.

Comment: Ah, I see now what you mean. I will post an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Right after the `alert` you could reload the page with [`location.reload(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload), which comes down to starting a new game:

```
if(guesses >= max){
    alert("You're dead. Press OK to start new game.")
    location.reload(true);
}
if(winner()) {
    alert("You won! Press OK to start new game.")
    location.reload(true);
}
```

Or, you could hide the part of the form that has the buttons and display a message instead:

```js
var gallows = new Array("--------\n|      |\n|\n|\n|\n|\n=====",
                        "--------\n|      O\n|\n|\n|\n|\n=====",
                        "--------\n|      O\n|      |\n|\n|\n|\n=====",
                        "--------\n|      O\n|     \\|\n|\n|\n|\n=====",
                        "--------\n|      O\n|     \\|/\n|\n|\n|\n=====",
                        "--------\n|      O\n|     \\|/\n|      |\n|\n|\n=====",
                        "--------\n|      O\n|     \\|/\n|      |\n|     /\n|\n=====",
                        "--------\n|      O\n|     \\|/\n|      |\n|     / \\\n|\n=====")
var guessChoices = new Array("summertime")
var guesses = 0
var max = gallows.length-1
var guessed = " "
var len = guessChoices.length - 1
var toGuess = guessChoices[Math.round(len*Math.random())].toUpperCase()
displayHangman()
displayToGuess()
displayGuessed()

function stayAway() {
  document.game.elements[3].focus()
  alert("Don't mess with this form element!")
}
function displayHangman() {
  document.game.status.value=gallows[guesses]
}
function displayToGuess() {
  pattern=""
  for(i=0;i<toGuess.length;++i) {
    if(guessed.indexOf(toGuess.charAt(i)) != -1)
      pattern += (toGuess.charAt(i)+" ")
      else pattern += "_ "
        }
  document.game.toGuess.value=pattern
}
function displayGuessed() {
  document.game.guessed.value=guessed
}
function badGuess(s) {
  if(toGuess.indexOf(s) == -1) return true
  return false
}
function winner() {
  for(i=0;i<toGuess.length;++i) {
    if(guessed.indexOf(toGuess.charAt(i)) == -1) return false
      }
  return true
}
function guess(s){
  if(guessed.indexOf(s) == -1) guessed = s + guessed
  if(badGuess(s)) ++guesses
  displayHangman()
  displayToGuess()
  displayGuessed()
  if(guesses >= max){
    gameOver(0);
  }
  if(winner()) {
    gameOver(1);
  }
}
function gameOver(outcome) {
  // Make appropriate message visible, and only that one (you won, you lost)
  document.querySelectorAll('.result')[outcome].style.display = '';
  document.querySelectorAll('.result')[1-outcome].style.display = 'none';
  // Show game-over message area and hide buttons
  document.querySelector('#gameover').style.display = '';
  document.querySelector('#playing').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<FORM NAME="game">
  <PRE>
    <TEXTAREA NAME="status" ROWS="7" COLS="16"
     ONFOCUS="stayAway()"></TEXTAREA>
  </PRE>
  <P>
    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="toGuess"
     ONFOCUS="stayAway()"> Enter this word in the promo code box!<BR>
    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="guessed"
     ONFOCUS="stayAway()"> Letters you have guessed.<BR>
  </P>   
  <div id="playing">
    <P>Enter your next guess.</P>
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" A " ONCLICK="guess('A')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" B " ONCLICK="guess('B')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" C " ONCLICK="guess('C')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" D " ONCLICK="guess('D')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" E " ONCLICK="guess('E')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" F " ONCLICK="guess('F')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" G " ONCLICK="guess('G')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" H " ONCLICK="guess('H')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" I " ONCLICK="guess('I')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" J " ONCLICK="guess('J')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" K " ONCLICK="guess('K')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" L " ONCLICK="guess('L')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" M " ONCLICK="guess('M')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" N " ONCLICK="guess('N')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" O " ONCLICK="guess('O')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" P " ONCLICK="guess('P')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" Q " ONCLICK="guess('Q')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" R " ONCLICK="guess('R')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" S " ONCLICK="guess('S')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" T " ONCLICK="guess('T')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" U " ONCLICK="guess('U')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" V " ONCLICK="guess('V')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" W " ONCLICK="guess('W')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" X " ONCLICK="guess('X')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" Y " ONCLICK="guess('Y')">
    <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" Z " ONCLICK="guess('Z')">
  </div>
  <div id="gameover" style="display:none">
    <div><span class="result">You're dead.</span><span class="result">You won!</span></div>
    <div>Thanks for playing... try again tomorrow!</div>
  </div>
</FORM>
```

Side note: when the page loads there is a JavaScript error

> document.game is undefined in line 30

This is because the DOM has not yet loaded when your script runs. To solve that, move the `script` tag right to the end of your `body` tag:

```
<body>
   ... 
   <script>
       // all your code
   </script>
</body>
```

Comment: OK, I see what you are saying but I don't wish for it to reload either. So can I just tell it to end? This reasoning behind this is that I only want a person to be able to play the game once a day and I will reset it with a new word to solve every day. Make sense?

Comment: So what do you want to happen then? A blank screen? A blank page with a message "Thanks for playing, see you next time" ? Disable all buttons? Can you clarify?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry.....yes, something like  "Thanks for playing.....try again tomorrow!"

Comment: And not allow the player to be able to guess anymore (if they got hung) because they shouldn't be able to continue and guess letters to solve the word.

Comment: OK, I added a snippet that does that.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed!!  Thank you very much! You have made me a very happy lady today! Hope the rest of your day is wonderful!

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted via the grey checkmark at the left of the answer.

Comment: Ok, will do.....but now I have noticed that I refresh the page, the game clears and starts over yet I only want the person to be able to do it once a day. Is there a way to make that possible?

Comment: For that you would really need a server and user accounts. Because even if you would solve it for one browser session (with cookies), someone could just open a new session and still play the game, so that wont really work. Do you have a server with programming environment, like PHP?

Comment: Yes, I do. What are you thinking?

Comment: You should let users sign up and log in. This should be managed in a database that has a user table, keeping username and password and the last time they played the game. At every started game you update that timestamp, and when a request is made for a new game you only allow it if the timestamp is before last midnight. This requires a lot of setup and coding, and really goes beyond the scope of this question. I suggest you read a bit about all that, try doing it (if this really is what you think you need) and then ask a new question in case of problems.

Comment: Oh wow....  this does seem to be beyond my realm of coding. lol   But I do love a good challenge, so I just might play around and see how far I can get with it. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: But carefully outweigh if it really is worth the effort. For one, you'll have to bother players to first log in. This will maybe downgrade the user-experience, although you can use facebook-login or google-login, ... etc. But if you want to go for a light solution, then look into cookies or "localstorage". The downside is that the user can still open a new browser session (or on another device) and still play. But maybe you can live with that. You have to outweigh the development cost against the benefits it will bring over a simpler cookie solution.

Comment: That is a good point you brought up. I happen to have a website that members (the whole premise of creating this hangman was to give them a fun activity while I was learning to code!), are required to log in with username and password, so that may be just the solution I am looking for. However, the amount of time and trial and error, in my case, may not make it worthwhile.